# Choice for priors for exponential spatial covariance

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, spatial

I doing spatial bayesian data analysis, I am assuming a no-nugget exponential covariance. I have tried a variety of priors for the sills and range parameters (gamma, inverse gamma etc.) , unfortunately the convergence diagonstics are typically horrible.

I am wondering how to figure out the poor mixing I observe, is there something I can do to make the MCMC chain behave better?

Answer (score 4):

Diggle and Ribeiro discuss this in their book ("[Model-based Geostatistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387329072)"): see section 5.4.2.  They quote some research suggesting that re-parameterization might help a little.  For an exponential model (a Matern model with kappa = 1/2) this research suggests using the equivalent of log(sill/range) and log(range).  Diggle and Ribeiro themselves recommend a profile likelihood method to investigate the log-likelihood surface.  Their software is implemented in the R package [geoRglm](http://gbi.agrsci.dk/~ofch/geoRglm/).

Have you looked at an experimental variogram to check that a zero nugget and an exponential shape are appropriate?

Comment: Thanks. I fitted a no nugget model to the likelihood using proc mixed, I guess I should compare the AICC with that of a model with nugget.

Comment: I would agree with whuber though that the visualization of the variogram cloud would be really helpful in determining if you choice of model seems appropriate.